# How can text wrap around a figure in tikzposter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure, wrap, tikzposter

While designing a poster with `tikzposter` I stumbled over a small issue. Usually one can use the `wrapfig` package to let text wrap around figures but in a box in tikzposter this seems to fail completely as shown in the MWE below.

Is there any way to wrap around a figure without using wrapfig so that this works as expected?

```
\documentclass[25pt, a4paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm]{tikzposter}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\institute{University}

\usetheme{Default}
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}
\column{.5}
\block[roundedcorners=40]{First block}{
Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. 

\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{0.5\textwidth}             
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption]
            \includegraphics{example-image}
        \end{tikzfigure}
\end{wrapfigure}

Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. Here some text that wraps around the figure. 
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When working in restricted width places you need to use `\linewidth` (or  `\columnwidth` in other context) to get a relevant length for scaling. Also `wrapfig` argument which you have provided with 5 is the number of lines to be used in the wrapped paragraph. Hence the rest leaks into the paragraph below. Using something like 11 does the job.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm]{tikzposter}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\institute{University}
\usetheme{Default}
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}
%\usepackage{graphicx}%<= Tikz loads this so no need.
\usepackage{wrapfig,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{columns}
\column{.5}
\block[roundedcorners=40]{First block}{
\kant[1-2]

\begin{wrapfigure}[12]{r}{0.5\linewidth}
        \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption]
            \includegraphics{example-image}
        \end{tikzfigure}
\end{wrapfigure}

\kant[1]
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that works beautifully.