# Wrap text around a figure inside a theorem environment in a poster

Tags: tikz-pgf, theorems, posters

I'd like to put a figure inside a proof in a poster. But if I do so, and if I wrap the text around the picture or a table, the picture is send away from the text. I have based on this question, but the theorem, lemma, corollary and so on environments break the wrapping.   The code is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187715/15542).

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm]{tikzposter}

  \usepackage{wrapfig,kantlipsum}
  \usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

  \begin{document}
  % \maketitle

  \begin{columns}
  \column{.5}
  \block[roundedcorners=10]{First block}{
  \kant[1]

  \begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption]
          \includegraphics{example-image}
      \end{tikzfigure}
  \end{wrapfigure}
  % \begin{proof}
  \kant[2]
  % \end{proof}
  }

  \column{.5}
  \block[roundedcorners=40]{Second block}{
  \kant[1]


  \begin{proof}
  \kant[2]
  \begin{wrapfigure}[11]{r}{0.5\linewidth}
      \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption]
          \includegraphics{example-image}
      \end{tikzfigure}
  \end{wrapfigure}       
    \kant[3]   
  \end{proof}
  }

  \end{columns}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "the picture is send away from text", but note that you get the following message in the `.log` file for the second `wrapfigure`: *Package wrapfig Warning: wrapfigure used inside a conflicting environment on input line N.* Simple fix is I suppose to not use a `proof` environment at all, but do the layout manually.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. A second page is created and the figure is relocated there, not inside the proof as expected. Yeap, so, I'll fix it manually.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't actually notice the second page.

Comment: This has come up many times, with different solutions proposed.  See the related questions shown to the right.