# TikzPoster - figure to the right, and wrapped text. Is it possible?

Tags: posters

Is it possible to have a figure to the right of you text, and at the same time have the text wrapped around it?

I've tried the package wrapfig, but doesnt seem to work.
Any advice?

sketch: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGoN4.jpg

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\block{A Title}{

\lipsum



\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of figure1]
  \includegraphics[height = 10cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{tikzfigure}%
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of figure2]
  \includegraphics[height = 10cm]{example-image-b}
  \end{tikzfigure}%
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}



\end{document}
```

Comment: a handrawn sketch of the desired output would be helpful

Comment: something like this
https://imgur.com/a/oMoI0GF

Comment: have alook at the answer below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can text wrap around a figure in tikzposter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187338/how-can-text-wrap-around-a-figure-in-tikzposter)

Answer (score 1):

a rough attempt -- have not worked with `tikzposter` -- two methods are outlined below -- alignment of the image  will change with the number of lines of text

[image]

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\usepackage{lipsum, wrapfig}


\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \block{A Title}{
                \lipsum[1]
                \begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.3\linewidth}
                    \begin{tikzfigure}[Caption]
                        \includegraphics{example-image}
                    \end{tikzfigure}
                \end{wrapfigure}
            \lipsum
            \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[scale=1,anchor=east,xshift=.3\linewidth,yshift=1cm,inner sep=0pt, label=below:Fig1:  label] {\includegraphics{example-image}};
            \lipsum
}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The second method doesn't work for me. The text appears on top of the figure. Also, a few suggestions: 1) remove the `[9]` for `wrapfigure`, so the required height will be calculated automatically? 2) add `[width=0.9\linewidth]` to `\includegraphics` so that the figure fits nicely into the wrapfigure space? 3) Add an image of the output?